# How to identify causes of high memory usage when using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, memory-management, google-chrome

Which techniques and methods can I use as a webcoder to locate causes of high memory usage within the jquery code I have defined ?
I am using Google Chrome stable, currently v7, if that helps.

Some parts can I replace with "regular" javascript, but that require more lines and less visibly to see whats happening. As far as I understand, the overhead jQuery adds is negligible.
Other parts can not, and are providing basic page functionality which means avoiding jQuery completely is not an option. Besides re-inventing the wheel is counter-productive.

Comment: you can even check cpu usage and check if it has any problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Chrome has a developers tool that can help trace your memory usage.  'm not sure what o/s you're using, but in Mac, you can go View, Developer, Developer Tools.  There's a resources tab and profiling tab that might be of use for you.

Comment: what about firebugs profiling , it also almost does the same thing. I think we can even use firebugs profiling.Just thought of sharing.

Comment: I was hoping for more than just "use X tool"

Comment: the reason i mentioned google chrome and not firefox was because he has tagged Google Chrome in the question.